# CMake remove first two characters regexp?

Tags: regex, cmake

I have a variable containing two include paths separated by whitespace:

```
PATHS=-I/home/user/application_x/include -I/home/user/application_y/include
```

I want to split this into two variables, and remove `-I`. This is what I have come up with so far:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "[^ ]*" APPLICATION_X ${PATHS})
STRING(REGEX MATCH "[^ ]*$" APPLICATION_Y ${PATHS})
```

The result:

```
APPLICATION_X=-I/home/user/application_x/include
APPLICATION_Y=-I/home/user/application_y/include
```

How can I remove `-I` from each string? The folder names 'application_x' and 'application_y' are not static, so only the first occurrence of `-I` should be removed, or else everything will break in case a folder is named 'application_-I'.

If it's possible to both split the variable and remove `-I` in one regexp per path, this would be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following using `REGEX MATCH`

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "/[^ ]*"  APPLICATION_X ${PATHS})
STRING(REGEX MATCH "/[^ ]*$" APPLICATION_Y ${PATHS})
```

Or you can use `REGEX REPLACE`:

```
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "-I([^ ]*)" "\\1"  APPLICATION_X ${PATHS})
STRING(REGEX REPLACE "-I([^ ]*)$" "\\1" APPLICATION_Y ${PATHS})
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer using `REGEX REPLACE` did not work for me (cmake 3.0.2 always returns the complete content of `${PATHS}` for some reason.

According tho the cmake documentation you'll also find the group using ${CMAKE_MATCH_1}:

```
()    Saves a matched subexpression, which can be referenced
      in the REGEX REPLACE operation. Additionally it is saved
      by all regular expression-related commands, including
      e.g. if( MATCHES ), in the variables CMAKE_MATCH_(0..9).
```

For your example it would be:

```
STRING(REGEX MATCH "-I([^ ]*)"  APPLICATION_X ${PATHS})
set(APPLICATION_X ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
STRING(REGEX MATCH "-I([^ ]*)$" APPLICATION_Y ${PATHS})
set(APPLICATION_Y ${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
```